# Binding click event on an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click, mouseclick-event

Is it possible to bind a click event to an iframe whose source is some other domain/third party?
If yes, how different is it from the conventional way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Rory mentioned in his answer,

> You cannot do this because of web browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

But there is a iframeTracker jQuery plugin, that claims to track clicks on iframes : https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery

Comment: thanks @Optimus Prime, that(iframeTracker) helped me to solve my issue.